# How to use Spring WebSocket client?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I'm trying to wrap my head around this whole Spring WebSocket thing, there are multiple tuturials with example applications including on Baeldung. The problem is that many don't work out of the box and almost always leave out important parts. There are also online WebSocket "echo" endpoints, how they're supposed to be used is a mystery to me.

Anyway, I can get everything up and running and receive messages on a UI with a provided JS sample using the code from [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/). But I don't want to receive messages on a UI, I want my Java code to receive messages and cannot figure out how to use the WebSocket/STOMP client in conjunction with the handler class nor am I clear about what component does what. I've tried it as "plain" WS and also as STOMP.

Check out this code that I've cobbled together from multiple tutorials:

```
@Component
public class SimpleStompSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        session.subscribe("/topic/greetings", this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
        HelloMessage msg = (HelloMessage) payload;
        System.out.println("Received : " + msg.getName());
    }
}
```

If `handleFrame()` get's called upon receiving a message, then what do I need the client for? Or am I supposed to call a client method inside `handleFrame`? But where do I do the initilal handshake or call a connect method? So that won't work anyway...

This is a client sample:

```
@Component
public class SimpleWebSocketClient {

    @Autowired
    private SimpleStompSessionHandler simpleStompSessionHandler;

    public void getHelloMessage() {
        StandardWebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();

        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

        stompClient.connect("/topic/greetings", simpleStompSessionHandler);

        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine(); // Don't close immediately.
    }
}
```

The good thing is there's a method to do the initial connect and I can plug in my handler, however how do I then react to incoming messages? This is all a bit fuzzy. I cannot find any comprehensive working pure Jave code example that shows how to do that, almost all examples use JS client-side.

Does anybody have a working client-side example of how to configure and set up a client in order to receive messages?

Comment: Did you find answer? I also want to have only client connected to remote ws (for example, another spring app on localhost:8080 with "my-ws" endpoint and different topics), but don't understand how to subscribe on different topics to get different messages

Comment: I am interested in this answer as well... I still have the structure of the normal websocket framework in mind, where there is a permanent method that handles all incoming messages. I cannot seem to figure it out with this one